# Handeling NULL pointer out argument in C# COM

Tags: c#, com, null, idl, typelib

I am working with a COM plugin interface that has the following function definition:

```
HRESULT foo ( [out, ref] VARIANT* a, [out, ref] VARIANT* b );
```

When using tlbimp (tlbimp2.exe from codeplex) the .NET library has the following interface function:

```
int foo ( out object a, out object b );
```

The problem is that the calling application will make the function call:

```
VARIANT a;
::InitVariant( &a );

plugin->foo( &a, NULL );
```

And in C# I implemented the function:

```
int foo ( out object a, out object b )
{
    a = 1;
    b = 2;

    return 0; // S_OK
}
```

When all is said and done the application actually gets a E_POINTER return and not S_OK.  I assume it is because of the NULL passed the the out parameter.

Is there a way to check if the address pointer is NULL in the C# implementation?

Note: out parameters are not initialized so you cant use the parameters at all.

I've tried implementing the interface as [in, out, ref] to force C# to use ( ref object a, ref object b ) but that did not work either.

**Update**

Hans is absolutely correct that we should have been calling the function with a NULL ptr if we were declaring it as [out,ref].

erurainon was also correct that we could just use IntPtr to get to the Variant*.

So here is how it was fixed:

```
int foo ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]out object a, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]out object b);
```

became

```
int foo ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]out object a, IntPtr b );
```

Now we can test for the NULL cases with:

```
if ( b == IntPtr.Zero )
```

However since we are dealing with Variant you can't just copy the value to the IntPtr like:

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr( myValue, b, false );
```

So following [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dimeby8/archive/2006/12/12/marshalling-variant-properties-in-c.aspx), you need to make a struct class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16)]
public struct PropVariant
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public VarEnum variantType;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IntPtr pointerValue;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public byte byteValue;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public long longValue;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public double dateValue;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public short boolValue;
}
```

And the final function looks like this:

```
int foo( out object a, IntPtr b )
{
    a = 100;

    if ( b != IntPtr.Zero )
    {
        var time = new PropVariant();
        time.dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
        time.variantType = VarEnum.VT_DATE;

        Marshal.StructureToPtr( time, b, false );
    }

    return 0; // S_OK
}
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans is right. Either you disallow your API to be called with NULL parameters, or you implement your C# function with `IntPtr` arguments and check for `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. I'm still hoping I can change the IDL file slightly to allow the application to still work with the plugin properly.

Comment: That actually worked just well, the big problem was copying the object to the address when it wasn't NULL/IntPtr.Zero, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the [MIDL docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367153%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
The [ref] attribute identifies a reference pointer. It is used simply to represent a level of indirection
....
A reference pointer has the following characteristics:
 - Always points to valid storage; never has the value NULL. A reference pointer can always be dereferenced.
```

The code is invalid, it passed NULL.  A direct violation of the [ref] contract.  This is where the bucks stops, you'll *have* to fix either the MIDL or the native code.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I figured. Unfortunately the version that calls with NULL has already been shipped.  Thankfully it's in a very minor part of the application, but still was just wondering.